# Get all img src with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I've html code with following `img src` parts:

```
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/...rw" srcset="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/...rw 2x" class="T75of DYfLw" width="551" height="310" alt="Screenshot Image"">
```

```
<img data-src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/...w720-h310-rw" ... data-srcset="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/... w1440-h620-rw 2x" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="width="551" height="310" alt="Screenshot Image">
```

I want to get all screenshots with attribute `alt=Screenshot Image`. So I need the value inside attribute `srcset` and `data-srcset` (2 different attribute names = 2 different cases).

I wrote this code:

```
List<String> src = htmlDocument.select("img[src]").stream()
                .filter(img -> img.attr("alt").equals("Screenshot Image"))
                .map(element -> element.absUrl("data-srcset").replace("2x", ""))
                //or for 1st case
                .map(element -> element.absUrl("srcset")..
                //
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But now I can't get this value from first case, where this attribute is `srcset`, not `data-srcset`. Can I get srcs for both scenarios without additional iteration - like not to create another stream and then unite all results into one collection? Maybe some regex and another method (seems like `.absUrl` doesn't work with regex) in Jsoup library can help?

And I don't like the part with `replace` (maybe some src will contain 2x as own part).

```
.map(element -> element.absUrl("data-srcset").replace("2x", ""))
```

But without this manipulation I'll get non-correct src.

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Z...=w1440-h620-rw 2x
```

Can I improve this `replace` solution with smth else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create a collection of collections and then `flatMap`:

```
List<String> src = htmlDocument.select("img[src]").stream()
            .filter(img -> img.attr("alt").equals("Screenshot Image"))
            .map(element -> {
                List<String> url = new ArrayList<>();
                url.add( element.absUrl("data-srcset").replace("2x", ""));
                url.add( element.absUrl("srcset"));
                return url;
            })
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For your last answer, assuming your URLs don't contain white spaces you could use:

```
StringUtils.substringBefore(element.absUrl("data-srcset")," ")
```

EDIT:

I assumed you could have both `srcset` and `data-srcset` in the same image. Reading again I end up with a better approach:

```
    List<String> src = htmlDocument.select("img[src]").stream()
                .filter(img -> img.attr("alt").equals("Screenshot Image"))
                .map(element -> StringUtils.isNotEmpty(element.absUrl("srcset")) ? 
                   element.absUrl("srcset") : 
                   element.absUrl("data-srcset").replace("2x", ""))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```